# Get edittext value from fragment in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a view pager like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        if (position == 0)
            return Fragment1.newInstance();
        else
            return Fragment2.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And `Fragment1` is

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private EditText et1;

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
 */
public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    return fragment;
}

public Fragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    et1 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.text1);
}

}
```

And `Fragmet2` is

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

private Button btnGetValues;
/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
 */
public static Fragment2 newInstance() {
    Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
    return fragment;
}

public Fragment2() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnGetValues = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnGetValues.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Here I want to get the value of edittext which is in fragment1.
        }
    });
}

}
```

As you see, I want to get the value of `EdiText` which is in `Fragment` on  `Button` click event, Button is in `Fragment2`. I have googled lot, But I can't find any answer, Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Try take one variable in Activity and assign EditText value to this variable and also change it value whenever EditText changed now try use this variable on Button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create String variable in Activity.

```
String text;
```

In activity put following functions:

```
void onTextChanged(String text){
   this.text=text;
   //Receive new text here
}


void onButtonClick(){
   //use current value of text variable as the latest edit text value in fragment1
}
```

And in fragment1 onClick of button:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    et1 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.text1);

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onTextChanged(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
   }
```

And in fragment 2:

```
btnGetValues.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Here I want to get the value of edittext which is in fragment1.
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onButtonClick();

 }
});
```

At the event of fragment change (Swipe), when fragment1 disappears and fragment2 is visible, you can simply collect all the values in a domain object and call an activity function passing this object.

Comment: @Gunaseelan you instead of typecasting activity you can also create an interface that has those 2 methods and make activity implement this interface. Finally pass the activity reference to the fragments.

Comment: I will try this and come back to you friend.

Comment: @vipulmittal i think you need use `rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);` instead of `getView().findViewById(R.id.text1);`

Comment: i am not sure that is going to make any difference. But this same code can be moved to onCreateView and rootView can be used in place of getView(). However, I think this should also work.

Comment: @vipulmittal if you test and you say that this work i accept that,

Comment: I am just saying it should. But the problem I am addressing is to get value from fragment1 on click of button in fragment2.

Comment: Ya friend, This works like awesome. But my question is if I has tons of elements in fragent1 means what will happen. Anyway I will accept this as answer.

Comment: @Gunaseelan what you can do is. At the event of fragment change (Swipe), when fragment1 disappears and fragment2 is visible, you can simply collect all the values in a domain object and call an activity function passing this object.

Comment: For multiple EditTexts this post here describes how to do it with ease. http://embry.io/post/2017/01/02/Multiple-EditTexts-in-Android.html